# How add the data fields that are manually added in cloud firestore as a constructor and how to call that in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, constructor

i have manually added the data in cloud firestore
[this how the data looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOTdl.png) .
Now using those fields i.e(id, location, model, equipmentCoordinates) how to create the constructor for that in flutter [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yki2l.png) and call it. so that i can use the constructor and call it everwhere i need. It will be so helpful if you can answer this.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it manually and also use this site for lengthy data models https://app.quicktype.io/

please check the image below for reference you can choose language and give data as you saved in the database,[image: quicktype]

Comment: how to do it without JSON format. because im not converting it into JSON and directly getting the data from firestore database documents

Comment: You will get data from the firestore but when you convert it only you can able to use it anywhere like below is how to fetch data,

Future<List<MyBookingsList>> getBookingsList() async {
    QuerySnapshot snapshot =
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('MyBookingsList').get();
    List<MyBookingsList> bookingsList = List.empty(growable: true);

    snapshot.docs.forEach((d) {
      MyBookingsList bookings = MyBookingsList.fromJson(d.data());
      bookingsList.add(bookings);
    });
    return bookingsList;
  }